# update state in a particular object of a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> what i am trying to do is 
>   update a state in the below component so that  i get the values from the name  of the respective nodes  and get data from the input i hope this can be done  so that i can get the object and update it . at last what i want is to do is update this state via form and get the object from the state but i want the values from each div  of a input and get in the format like

node : {
heading : '',
sub_heading:'',
image:'',
link:''
}

```js
  if (this.state.node1.name = 
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode.getAttribute('name')) {
            this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        }

 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            node1: {
                heading: '',
                sub_heading: '',
                link: '',
                image: '',
                name: 'node1'
            },
            node2: {
                heading: '',
                sub_heading: '',
                link: '',
                image: '',
                name: 'node2'
            },
            node3: {
                heading: '',
                sub_heading: '',
                link: '',
                image: '',
                name: 'node3'
            },
            node4: {
                heading: '',
                sub_heading: '',
                link: '',
                image: '',
                name: 'node4'
            },
            node5: {
                heading: '',
                sub_heading: '',
                link: '',
                image: '',
                name: 'node5'
            }
        }
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    submitForm = (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="admin-page-con">
                <form method="POST" encType="multipart/form" onSubmit={this.submitForm} >
                    <h1 className="form-header">theme page</h1>
                    <div ref="node1" className="image1 card">
                        <h2>node1</h2>
                        <input name="image" type="file" />
                        <input name="heading" onChange={this.handleChange} id="header1" placeholder="Header" type="text" /><br />
                        <input name="sub_heading" onChange={this.handleChange} className="input-2" id="Sub-Header" placeholder="sub-Header" type="text" />
                        <input name="link" onChange={this.handleChange} className="input-2" id="header3" placeholder="link" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div ref="node2" className="image1 card">
                        <h2>node2</h2>
                        <input name="image" type="file" />
                        <input name="heading" id="header1" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Header" type="text" /><br />
                        <input name="sub_heading" className="input-2" onChange={this.handleChange} id="header2" placeholder="Sub-Header" type="text" />
                        <input name="link" onChange={this.handleChange} className="input-2" id="header2" placeholder="link" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div ref="node3" className="image1 card">
                        <h2>node3</h2>
                        <input name="image" type="file" />
                        <input id="header1" name="heading" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Header" /><br />
                        <input name="sub_heading" className="input-2" onChange={this.handleChange} id="header2" type="text" placeholder="Sub-Header" />
                        <input name="link" onChange={this.handleChange} className="input-2" id="header2" placeholder="link" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div ref="node4" className="image1 card">
                        <h2>node4</h2>
                        <input name="image" type="file" />
                        <input id="header1" name="heading" onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Header" /><br />
                        <input className="input-2" name="sub_heading" onChange={this.handleChange} id="header2" type="text" placeholder="Sub-header" />
                        <input name="link" onChange={this.handleChange} className="input-2" id="header2" placeholder="link" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div ref="node5" className="image1 card">
                        <h2>node5</h2>
                        <input name="link" type="file" />
                        <input id="header1" name="heading" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Header" /><br />
                        <input className="input-2" name="sub_heading" id="header2" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Sub-Header" />
                        <input name="link" onChange={this.handleChange} className="input-2" id="header2" placeholder="link" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <input className="rect-btn submit-bt" type="submit" />
                </form>
            </div >
        )
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code well and then what's the issue you're facing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your state has objects with keys `nodeNum` to track the changes made in each `div`, you could make your `handleInputChange` function to take in another parameter.

Something like this below:

```
handleChange = (e, nodeName) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { name, value } = e.target
        this.setState({
           ...this.state,
           [nodeName]: {
                 [nam] : value
                 }
              })
            }
```

Then in each of your inputs, you call `handleInputChange` like `onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event, nodeNum)}`, and you can have a `value` attribute to your input which would be `this.state.nodeNum.inputName`

Comment: hey buddy thanks for the prompt response   nodeName ??  not able to get you  it will be really great if you  help me understand nodeName  and in my state all the name's are diffrent node1,node2,node3 .

Comment: Each of your `divs` have different `ref` attributes which you used to form an object in your `state` That is what I'm referring to as `nodeName` This is to that you can track each `inputs` in each `divs` and make sure you're storing each `value` in the right object in your state

Comment: i am new to react .  how can i user the ref name in the parameter  . help me so that i can understand the concept i have understood what you have told me but not able to apply  the solution at my end

Comment: For example, your first `<div>` has a ref of `node1`, So the `onChange` of the second `<input>` within that `div` will be `<input name='heading' onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e, 'node1')} />`

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help (:

Comment: Hello Pal , 

         I understand the answer you gave me  but i have a issue  it can be the lack of under standing or whatever the thing is when i apply the function on the input what it does is it overwrites the  value  for eg if i write test in the first input  and after that i write the test 2 in the second input the first key and value pairs  has been over written by the 2nd one .

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask. Can you please rephrase?? Thanks